# Getting spring boot jar files through gradle

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot

The spring framework wants users to use dependency tools to download the framework, so I am trying to use gradle. I got this sample from their website http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'root'
    version =  '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

I saved this to a file called build.gradle. Then in the CMD I went to the directory where the build.gralde file is located and type:

```
gradle build
```

It seemed to run fine but towards the building it's not working, here is the last logs I got from the command prompt:

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:findMainClass
```

:jar
:bootRepackage FAILED

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRepackage'.
```

> ```
> Unable to find main class
> ```

```
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 9.664 secs
```

I don't understand this ">     Unable to find main class". I only want to get all the jar files and put them inside WEB-INF/lib of my eclipse projects. I am extremely new at gradle. What should I do?

Comment: You're probably missing a class with a `main` method in your project (annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`).

Comment: @orid I don't understand, I haven't created any projects yet. I just want to download all spring boot jar files before creating any project. Am I missing something?

Comment: In that case add: `bootRepackage {enabled = false}` which switches the repacking off your project build script.

Comment: @orid done. It's working now, but I can only find one jar file (hello.jar)? Is this all?

Comment: Yes, it's the project jar (with no spring-boot "working" on it). This is sufficient in case you only want to test that the dependencies you are using are there, but useless in terms of spring boot application.

Comment: @orid
 um I'm totally confused now. Can't I do something like get all the jar files then put it inside the WEB-INF/lib folder of my project?

Comment: No, because that's not the way how Gradle works. There is no need to put them in a lib filder in your project, they will be downloaded to a local cache and added automatically to your project configuration. Gradle will package the dependencies in the resulting WAR file, but not in the source project.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear to me, acoording to your comments, what are you trying to achieve, if you don't have a project sources, but for some reason wants to download dependent libraries. Gradle doesn't work this way, all the libraries are dowloded on demand, that means, they are dowloaded then you, for example, try to build your source files.

The exception you get, means, that gradle spring boot plugin's task `bootRepackage` Didn't find a main class in your project. This main class is mandatory for this task, since the task creates a standalone executable jar.

Sure, it is possble to dowload deps by custom task, like:

```
task getDeps(type: Copy) {
  from sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  into 'runtime/'
}
```

But it seems, that you don't properly understand, how does it work. You should try to read [gradle user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/introduction.html) first and let gradle to build your project for you, but not just combine some libs.

Comment: I only want to get all the jar files and put them inside WEB-INF/lib of my eclipse projects. That's so far the only thing I know when using some libraries.

Comment: @morbidCode do you mean, you won't use gradle as build tool, but will use eclipse or something else? By the way, you may use a task from the answer and get what you want by plaing witn into parameter and changing the configuration to get required libs.